# Filebeat and downstream availability

Tags: logging, elasticsearch, elk

I read here and there that a broker (like *Redis*) might not be required in the log pipeline (typically ELK) when *Filebeat* is used.

From *Filebeat*'s official page:

> [Filebeat] is intelligent enough to deal with [...] the temporary
>   unavailability of the downstream server, so you never lose a log line.

However it is unclear for me how exactly it does that, what are mechanisms, what are the limitations, how that can be configured / fine-tuned (I see no options for that in the *Filebeat*'s default config file).

All in all, is it really worthy considering not to use a broker, if using *FIlebeat*? (I guess the answer is *"it depends"*, but given that it is unclear what *Filebeat* is exactly capable of in terms of fault tolerance, it's not easy to make an educated choice).